# A cohomology associated to a vector field on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, cohomology, differential-forms

**Edit:**  Accoring to the comment of Asura Path I revise the question.

Let $X$ be  a  vector field  on a  Riemannian manifold  $(M,g)$. So  we have  a $1$-form $\beta$  with $\beta(Y)=\langle Y,X\rangle_g$.

We  consider the following subcomplex of de Rham complex $\Omega^*(M)$: $$\{\alpha\in \Omega^*(M)\mid d\alpha=\alpha \wedge \beta\}$$

This  generates a  cohomology.  For  zero vector  field  we get the  standard de Rham  cohomology.

Is this  cohomology always a finite dimensional space? Does it depend on the  Riemannian structure? Does it contain  some  dynamical information about the  vector field  $X$?

Is there  an  appropriate  analogy  of this  cohomology in algebraic topology or  other type of  cohomologis? (In the  context of  algebraic topology,  we replace  $1$-form $\beta$ with a  $1$-cochain and  the  exterior  derivative  with coboundary and wedge product with cup product)

Comment: "This generates a cohomology with the standard exterior derivation." That sentence sounds somewhat confusing to me. Do you just mean that it is a complex and we can compute its cohomology (note that mentioning exterior derivation seems to be redundant, since you already said that it is a subcomplex, so there is only one possible differential on it)?

Comment: @AsuraPath thank you for your comment. Yes it is redindant. I will revise it.

Comment: I changed $$\beta(Y)=<Y,X>_g$$ to $$\beta(Y)=\langle Y,X\rangle_g.$$ That is standard usage. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  Thanks a lot  for  your  edit  and  informing me of standard usage.

Comment: Two comments: (1) You don't mention it, but there are other conditions for $\alpha$ to be in the subcomplex: for instance, $\alpha \wedge d\beta = 0$.  Hence cocycles in the subcomplex are killed by exterior product with both $\beta$ and $d\beta$.  (2) If $X$ is nowhere vanishing, so that neither is $\beta$, then the cohomology of the subcomplex is trivial: since the differential agrees up to a sign with exterior product by $\beta$ and exterior product by a nowhere-vanishing 1-form defines an exact sequence.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill  Thank  you very much   for  your  comment.. Regarding your  second  statement (2): Yes  wedge product with a non vanishing 1-form gives  an  exact sequence  on whole  de  Rham  complex  not necessarilly on the  subcomplex I  considered in the post. For example put $M=\mathbb{R}$. Then $dx$ lies in the  subcomplex we are considering but it is not the  differential of any $0$-form in our subcomplex. Because $0$-forms in the  subcomplex  are scalar multiple of  $e^x$. I try  to  understand your  first  statement.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill so the  cohomology we described in the post can be non trivial even if $\beta$   is non trivial. Now  I  realize that this  cohomology is  infinie  dimensional  for  $M=\mathbb{R}$  and $\beta=dx$.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill  Am I  mistaken?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Let me know if I am misinterpreting. If $X$ is the zero vector field, then $\beta$ is the zero covector field, so for any $\alpha$ we have $\alpha \wedge \beta=0$. Then the condition for your subcomplex just makes it the subcomplex of cocycles, which has trivial differential. This subcomplex does not give the same cohomology as the de Rham complex.

Comment: @ConnorMalin  yes you are right. Thanks for your comment. I was mistaken about zero field. So I think that the cohomology In this post is almost useless.  However I do not know if there are non trivial examples in pure algebraic context?

Comment: @op, u might want to look up "twisted de rham cohom" but nb this is about taking differential $d+\lambda$ for a form $\lambda$. (so u're taking the cycles wrt this differential as ur subcomplex). Eg if the vec field is Hamiltonian u can check u get just dR cohom (multiply by exp(f)). Hopefully this will help, but doesn't answer ur question sadly

Comment: @op further if u want to think algebraically then normally ppl consider the differential I mentioned. It computes, in the case of an exact form, something like vanishing cycles cohomology according to some beautiful work of sabbah